# Qui est le "parent" d'une dépendance

Tags: vocabulaire

Comment appelle-t-on quelque chose qui est le "parent" d'une dépendance ?

En d'autres mots :
 - Le "parent" d'une dépendance
 - Prédécesseur d'une dépendance

Comment: J'ai du mal à comprendre ta demande. Ton *autre mot* semble concerner au contraire de ce qui précède et du titre : *Quelque chose **dont** dépend autre chose*. Par ailleurs, un contexte serait nécessaire. Il est des mots très attachés à des domaines précis.

Comment: Est-ce "a dependent" au sens anglais ?

Comment: @aCOSwt Le contexte serait la chose qui est nécessaire à une autre chose pour fonctionner.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Non.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je me suis trompé dans le titre. C'est corrigé.

Comment: 1: "en d'autres mots" répète maintenant ce qui a déjà été dit. 2: Pourrais-tu donner des exemples de "parents (et enfants?) de dépendances" ?

Comment: Si tu es anglophone, tu peux poser ta question en anglais pour qu'il n'y ai pas de mal entendu.

Comment: arbre de dependance en grammaire, par exemple?

Comment: @jlliagre Un logiciel à besoin (enfant) d'un autre logiciel (partent) pour fonctionner.

Comment: @William — Le "parent" d'une dépendance n'a pas de nom particulier mais on va trouver des expressions avec le mot "principal" comme "bâtiment principal". En fait, le terme "les dépendances" regroupe tous les bâtiments en dehors du bâtiment principal qu'on va appeler simplement par son nom : château, manoir etc. En fait on parle du château et de ses dépendances, mais jamais des dépendances et de leur château. On garde les petites constructions pour la fin de la phrase.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi cette question a été fermée. Rassurez-moi, je ne suis pas le seul à avoir compris une question qui me semble parfaitement claire ?